# tf.data: "mixing" batch sizes?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am working in TF 1.4.1 using the Dataset API. I have two sets of input data, `x` and `y`, with the same number of elements each. For both `x` and `y`, I have large context arrays `context_x` and `context_y`, say of size 10000-by-10.

The context varies for each input batch (although it is the same for each sample within a batch), so it makes sense to link them together in the input pipeline. I cannot store all the context arrays for all of the batches in the graph and then read from there, since storing all of them statically in the graph is prohibitive in terms of the memory required. What I *can* do is input a single context array for the current batch, and I want to include this in my input pipeline.

Also note that in my graph the context array goes through some convolutional layers, which effectively reduce it to a manageable size, much smaller than original, so that I then `tile` it with other features specific to the samples in the batch and carry on with the rest of my task. So even though I will need to eventually replicate to batch size, I can do this on an feature vector extracted from the context array that is of much smaller size.

I am using the following type of code to build a dataset that should feed a batch of `x` and `y` samples along with their context to my graph:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# Small data input
x = np.arange(100)
y = np.arange(100)

# Large context array for both x  and y
context_x = np.random.rand(1, 10000, 10)
context_y = np.random.rand(1, 10000, 10)

# Create datasets
dataset_x = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x)
dataset_y = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(y)

# same context should be repeated for every data item
dataset_context_x = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(context_x)
dataset_context_x = dataset_context_x.repeat()
dataset_context_y = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(context_y)
dataset_context_y = dataset_context_y.repeat()

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((dataset_x, dataset_context_x))
dataset = dataset.concatenate( tf.data.Dataset.zip((dataset_y, dataset_context_y)) )
dataset = dataset.batch(32)

iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
(x_iter, context_iter) = iterator.get_next()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(iterator.initializer)
    while True:
        try:
            xi, ci = sess.run([x_iter, context_iter])
            print(xi.shape, ci.shape)
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            break
```

The output indicates that the large context arrays are replicated for every sample `x[i]` and `y[i]`:

```
((32,), (32, 10000, 10))
((32,), (32, 10000, 10))
((32,), (32, 10000, 10))
((32,), (32, 10000, 10))
((32,), (32, 10000, 10))
((32,), (32, 10000, 10))
((8,), (8, 10000, 10))
```

This will waste a lot of memory, since all of the 32 `10000`-by-`10` slices will be identical! How should I use the Dataset API so that this unnecessary copying of the context arrays is avoided, and I get an output such as `((32,), (1, 10000, 10))` for each batch? You could think of this as mixing batch sizes, 32 for `x` and `y` while 1 for the context arrays.

Comment: If the data in the "context" array always the same, can't you define it manually outside of your input pipeline and just use that tensor in the network instead?
Something like `context = tf.constant(...)` would do the trick (and if you need to change the values during training, use `tf.Variable(trainable=False)`)

Comment: @GPhilo due to the size of the context arrays, storing all of them in the graph is unfortunately not feasible. The context also varies for each batch (although it is the same for each sample within a batch), so it makes sense to link them together in the input pipeline.

Comment: You might want to clarify that in the question then, because you're saying that "This context is shared among all samples", not just those in a batch. About the size problem, you won't be able to work around that I'm afraid. If the data doesn't fit in the graph when you declare it manually, it also won't fit when you try to run the input pipeline.

Comment: @GPhilo thank you, clarification added! As I said, the context is different for each batch, but same for every sample within one batch. What I mean is that I cannot store all the context arrays for all of the batches in the graph and then read from there, since storing all of them statically in the graph is prohibitive in terms of the memory required. The 2GB limit for a `GraphDef` is quickly exceeded and the graph cannot be store to disk anymore, for example. In contrast, what I *can* do is input a single context array for the current batch, and I want to include this in my input pipeline.

Comment: Ok, now I understand better. My next question is, however, assuming you manage to get a dataset with output sizes `[ (32,), (10000, 10) ]` (which could be done removing the `.repeat()` on `dataset_context_*`), don't you need to replicate your context `batch_size` times in your graph afterwards to compute the batch? (Depending on how `tf.tile` is implemented that might be more memory-efficient or not. My feeling is `tile` just copies the data, though..)

Comment: @GPhilo Great question! The way it works is that in my graph the context array goes through some convolutional layers, which effectively reduce it to a manageable size, much smaller than original, so that I then `tile` it with other features specific to the samples in the batch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here's my tentative solution. Please note that I'm assuming your data is somehow ordered, so that when you build batches of `x` the next `context_x` you read is always the one related to the current batch.

```
import os
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1' # running on CPU
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# Small data input
x = np.arange(100)
y = np.arange(100)

# Large context array for both x  and y
context_x = np.random.rand(1, 10000, 10)
context_y = np.random.rand(1, 10000, 10)

# Create datasets
dataset_x = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x).batch(32)
dataset_y = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(y).batch(32)

# same context should be repeated for every data item
dataset_context_x = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(context_x)
dataset_context_x = dataset_context_x.repeat() # here just for demonstration purposes. Ideally you'll have enough context data to match the batches
dataset_context_y = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(context_y)
dataset_context_y = dataset_context_y.repeat() # here just for demonstration purposes. Ideally you'll have enough context data to match the batches

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((dataset_x, dataset_context_x))
dataset = dataset.concatenate( tf.data.Dataset.zip((dataset_y, dataset_context_y)) ) # This stacks all 'x' samples on top of all 'y' samples. Is this really what you wanted?

iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
(x_iter, context_iter) = iterator.get_next()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(iterator.initializer)
    while True:
        try:
            xi, ci = sess.run([x_iter, context_iter])
            print(xi.shape, ci.shape)
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            break
```

In your implementation, remove the `dataset_context_* = dataset_context_*.repeat()` lines.

The key difference with your pipeline is that I'm batching `x` *before* zipping it with the context, so that the context doesn't get replicated. This, however, requires you to be careful in handling the data loading (hence my assumption above).

Comment: Seems to work exactly like I wanted! Your assumption on ordering of the data also holds in my case. Regarding stacking all 'x' samples on top of all 'y' samples -- this is also what I want. I can then shuffle the resulting dataset and feed samples to the network so that it sees data from different contexts on each iteration; instead of first all batches from context 1, then context 2, et cetera.